# Error: Exited: ExitFailure 45

Tags: c

I tried to solve project euler's 10th question using an somewhat-optimized algorithm for finding prime numners

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

long long int main() {
    int flag =1;
    long int lim = 199999; //upto which the prime is to be generated
    long int purposedPrime = 2;
    long int PrimeSet[200000] = {0}, count=0; 
    long int i;
    float sRoot_PP;
    long long int Sum = 0 ; //This is for prj_euler :)
    PrimeSet[count] = 2; count++; purposedPrime++;
    PrimeSet[count] = purposedPrime ; count++;
    Sum = 5 ;
    while(purposedPrime < lim){
        flag = 1;
        purposedPrime += 2;
        sRoot_PP = sqrt(purposedPrime);
        for(i=0; i<count; i++){
            if(PrimeSet[i]>sRoot_PP) break;
            if(purposedPrime % PrimeSet[i] == 0){ flag = 0; break;}
        }
        if(flag == 1){
            PrimeSet[count] = purposedPrime ;
            count++;
            Sum += purposedPrime;
        }
    }

    printf("Total Count: %d", count);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Sum : %ld", Sum);
    return Sum;
}
```

I ran it in local machine: `Codeblocks with MinGW in Win8`. The output

```
Total Count: 17984
Sum : 1709600813
Process returned 7096800813 (0x65E6702D) execution time : 0.063 s
Press any key to continue
```

I ran it in [codepad](http://codepad.org/q9D8lCjD) . The output

```
Total Count: 17984
Sum : 1709600813
Exited: ExitFailure 45
```

In both the cases the output is incorrect. I personally think that has to do something with the error shown. What is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pointing to you returning a non-zero value from your main function. To fix that error, just replace `return Sum` with `return 0`. It won't help your results, though. Similarly, I'd change the return value of `main` to just be `int`, but that won't actually make any difference, either.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me why is it outputting erroneous results? I mean, the algorithm is perfectly fine, and it works well for lower prime numbers

Comment: What is the value of the first erroneous result? Knowing that might provide a hint as to the problem. I suspect it might be a silent overflow error, but I'd have to research Euler's 10th question to have any deeper insight, unless I can spot an obvious error in your code, which is a possibility if I know at what value it fails.

Comment: OK, I get what you're trying to do now. Fairly straightforward, and I see no obvious error. Two things I'd try: 1) change your `float` to a `double`, and 2) change your `long int` to `long long int`. If your compiler supports it, you might also try using `__int128_t` or similar. (Oh, and as a non-programming suggestion change `purposedPrime` to `proposedPrime`.)

Comment: The error: my carelessness. what supposed to be 2 million i used 200 thousand. anyways, thanks :)

Comment: Good to know. Good luck with your endeavor.